# Can't get chrome.system.memory.getInfo. from Chrome Extensions API. Memory is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memory')
code:

```js
    chrome.system.memory.getInfo(function(info) {
      console.log(info);
    });
```

Manifest:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Memory Monitor",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
        {
          "js": [
            "scripts/content.js"
          ],
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
      ],
  "permissions": [
      "system.memory"
  ]
}
```

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Adding more details: That's it.

Comment: Most APIs are not available in content_scripts.

[Understand content script capabilities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#capabilities)

Comment: for "background" it is not available also. what should I use then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in the background.

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "chrome.system.memory.getInfo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "system.memory"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
console.log("background.js");
chrome.system.memory.getInfo(function (info) {
  console.log(info);
});
```